# Error Returning Array<Struct> as Array<Any>

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, protocols

I have a function that can return several different Types depending on the internal conditions of my data structure, so I return an Array of Any and leave a comment explaining the types it could be. (I'm sure there's a better solution, but I don't know what it is). That gave me the error

> Cannot convert return expression of type '[S]' to return type '[Any]'

where `S` is a pure-Swift struct. I've boiled this down to a toy example that exemplifies the issue:

```
protocol P { }  // protocol
struct S: P { } // struct conforming to protocol

// Will Compile: all protocols implicitly conform to Any
func returnAny() -> Any {
    return S()
}

// refuses to compile with above error
func returnArrayOfAny() -> [Any] {
    return [S]()
}

// oddly enough, this will compile and work
func returnMappedArrayOfAny() -> [Any] {
    return [S]().map { $0 }
}
```

Am I missing something in the way Arrays or Protocols work in Swift? Casting `[S]() as! [P]` also allows the function to return, although I'm not sure why the cast has to be forced, since `S` *does* conform to `P`.

[I've made a Playground with the issue](https://cloudup.com/c0fonzGggo2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same issue discussed by Brent Simmons in [this blog post](http://inessential.com/2015/08/02/swift_diary_7_protocols_arrays_and_c). There is some interesting discussion [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/brentsimmons/status/627994188584321024) about it; I would encourage you to read through the conversation.

The main point is that `[S]` and `[Any]` may have fundamentally different storage/layout, so a cast between them is nontrivial (can't necessarily be done in constant time). `map` is a convenient way around this, making it explicit that you're building up a new array.

In the case of an empty array, you can simply `return []`.

Comment: In my case I had a tableView with 3 sections, which had 3 types of cells each of which represented different data types. Tapping on a section header makes an Analytics call with the data in that section, so in my case it was never an empty list. I guess I'll just map over them in this case, or figure out some kind of functional composition to work around the static analysis. Thanks for your help!